# Multiple Inheritance with same Base Classes in Python

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to wrap my head around multiple inheritance in python.

Suppose I have the following base class:

```
class Structure(object):
    def build(self, *args):
        print "I am building a structure!"
        self.components = args
```

And let's say I have two classes that inherit from it:

```
class House(Structure):
    def build(self, *args):
        print "I am building a house!"
        super(House, self).build(*args)

class School(Structure):
    def build(self, type="Elementary", *args):
        print "I am building a school!"
        super(School, self).build(*args)
```

Finally, a create a class that uses multiple inheritance:

```
class SchoolHouse(School, House):
    def build(self, *args):
        print "I am building a schoolhouse!"
        super(School, self).build(*args)
```

Then, I create a SchoolHouse object and run `build` on it:

```
>>> sh = SchoolHouse()
>>> sh.build("roof", "walls")
I am building a schoolhouse!
I am building a house!
I am building a structure!
```

So I'm wondering -- what happened to the `School` class? Is there any way to get Python to run both somehow?

I'm wondering specifically because there are a fair number of Django packages out there that provide custom `Managers` for models. But there doesn't appear to be a way to combine them without writing one or the other of the Managers as inheriting from the other one. It'd be nice to just import both and use both somehow, but looks like it can't be done?

Also I guess it'd just help to be pointed to a good primer on multiple inheritance in Python. I have done some work with Mixins before and really enjoy using them. I guess I just wonder if there is any elegant way to combine functionality from two different classes when they inherit from the same base class.

**Yup, silly me. It was a typo all along. I feel very dumb. I promise, I always put the right class in when I super in real life, it was only when I was cutting and pasting to try this out that I messed up.**

Comment: Why are you calling `super` with `School` in `SchoolHouse`? You're supposed to pass the subclass, not any of the superclasses (you do it correctly in the other classes).

Comment: You've tagged this question with Django, so I imagine you're dealing with models. Keep in mind that you can't override attributes that are Field types... Django will throw you errors. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#field-name-hiding-is-not-permitted for more information about that.

Comment: For an excellent primer, see Raymond Hettinger's [Super considered super](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/).

Comment: @delnan That'd be a typo :) No wonder it wasn't working!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `super()` call in `SchoolHouse` is wrong.

It is:

```
super(School, self).build(*args)
```

It should be:

```
super(SchoolHouse, self).build(*args)
```